# Display Camera Feed On Website To Scan QR Code

Tags: java, web, qr-code

I am using applet for scanning the QR Code. I am using this applet in my website.Advantage of using applet is that , since it is java program the scanning is fast. But the problem is that it is an old technology.Also user need to dowload the JRE to run the applet.

Another option is to use jquery for accesing the webcam.But the problem is QR scanning is very slow with jquery.

Anybody please help to find a better technology to build a Qr code scanner in my website using java, since it is very fast.

Best Regards,

Alenlee MJ